# Build iOS framework towards My Mac with Xcode 11.2 report errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgrade my xcode recently.
When I build my iOS frameworks towards My Mac, most of them works fine. However one framework build failed. The error as follow:

> My Mac doesn’t support any of XXX.framework’s architectures. You can add My Mac’s x86_64h architecture to XXX.framework’s Architectures build setting.

I have tried add x86_64h, x86_64, and arm64e to valid architecture, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to compare build settings between these frameworks, but failed to find out an solution.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then I changed `Valid Architectures` to `arm64 x86_64`.
After this, I was able to build the framework and use it.